# opening and printing multiple crystal reports from a windows app

Tags: c#, winforms, printing, crystal-reports

I am going to be building a windows forms application that will essentially queue up and print off several crystal reports.

Really at this point, I just need some direction of a way to go forward with this.  What is the best way to open a crystal report in a windows forms app?  Are there libraries developed to assist with this etc?

I will be using C# .net 2.0 (probably...but maybe 4.0)

thanks for your time in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is the [Crystal Reports RunTime](http://www.businessobjects.com/jump/xi/crvs2010/default.asp). Or if you need to use an older version for some reason:  http://resources.businessobjects.com/support/additional_downloads/runtime.asp#09

Then use the `ReportDocument` class.  It has a `Load` and a `Print` method - it's pretty  straight forward to use.  There is also a report viewer that you can use to let the user view the report.